# Run a script in the same shell(bash)

Tags: linux, shell, command

My problem is specific to the running of SPECCPU2006(a benchmark suite).
After I installed the benchmark, I can invoke a command  called "specinvoke" in terminal to run a specific benchmark. I have another script, where part of the codes are like following:

```
cd (specific benchmark directory)
specinvoke &
pid=$!
```

My goal is to get the PID of the running task. However, by doing what is shown above, what I got is the PID for the "specinvoke" shell command and the real running task will have another PID.

However, by running `specinvoke -n` ,the real code running in the specinvoke shell will be output to the stdout. For example, for one benchmark,it's like this:

```
# specinvoke r6392
#  Invoked as: specinvoke -n
# timer ticks over every 1000 ns
# Use another -n on the command line to see chdir commands and env dump
# Starting run for copy #0
../run_base_ref_gcc43-64bit.0000/milc_base.gcc43-64bit < su3imp.in > su3imp.out 2>> su3imp.err
```

Inside it it's running a binary.The code will be different from benchmark to benchmark(by invoking  under different benchmark directory). And because "specinvoke" is installed and not just a script, I can not use "`source specinvoke`".

So is there any clue? Is there any way to directly invoke the shell command in the same shell(have same PID) or maybe I should dump the `specinvoke -n` and run the dumped materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still do something like:

```
cd (specific benchmark directory)
specinvoke &
pid=$(pgrep milc_base.gcc43-64bit)
```

If there are several invocation of the  `milc_base.gcc43-64bit binary`, you can still use

```
pid=$(pgrep -n milc_base.gcc43-64bit)
```

Which according to the man page:

> -n
>
> ```
> Select only the newest (most recently started) of the matching
> processes
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this probably will not work well. That's because I might have already started several other processes with the same name milc_base.gcc43-64bit...You know what I mean? Is there any way to directly get the PID of the process which is invoked by the last specinvoke Shell script?

Answer (score 0):

when the process is a direct child of the subshell:

```
ps -o pid= -C=milc_base.gcc43-64bit --ppid $!
```

when not a direct child, you could get the info from pstree:

```
pstree -p $! | grep -o 'milc_base.gcc43-64bit(.*)'
```

output from above (PID is in brackets): milc_base.gcc43-64bit(9837)